# How to create a single character String

Tags: swift, swift3

I've reproduced this problem in a Swift playground but haven't solved it yet...

I'd like to print one of a range of characters in a UILabel.  If I explicitly declare the character, it works:

```
// This works.
let value: String = "\u{f096}"
label.text = value  // Displays the referenced character.
```

However, I want to construct the String.  The code below appears to produce the same result as the line above, except that it doesn't.  It just produces the String `\u{f096}` and not the character it references.

```
// This doesn't work
let n: Int = 0x95 + 1
print(String(n, radix: 16))  // Prints "96".
let value: String = "\\u{f0\(String(n, radix: 16))}"
label.text = value  // Displays the String "\u{f096}".
```

I'm probably missing something simple.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could be just the excess "\" in `"\\u{f0\(String(n,radix: 16))}"`? Just guessing - I have no idea how string formats work in swift.

Comment: Agreed it could be but then it doesn't compile.  That's why I reproduced the problem in a playground before posting.  I get the error: Scratch.playground:7:27: Expected '}' in \u{...} escape sequence

Comment: Maybe [How to create a string with format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24097543/205233) has a hint.

Comment: Same problem.  The initial backslash still needs to be escaped and the resulting String comes out as as "\u{f096}" not the required character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about stop using string conversion voodoo and use standard library type [UnicodeScalar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unicodescalar)?

> You can also create Unicode scalar values directly from their numeric representation.

```
let airplane = UnicodeScalar(9992)
print(airplane) 
// Prints "✈︎"
```

*UnicodeScalar.init there is actually returning optional value, so you must unwrap it.*

If you need `String` just convert it via [Character](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/character) type to String.

```
let airplaneString: String = String(Character(airplane)) // Assuming that airplane here is unwrapped
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks.